# Invalid ZoneDateTime parsing in Java / Scala

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to parse dates from strings to `ZonedDateTime`s and I've come across a bizzare problem.

```
2020-11-01T01:00-05:00[America/New_York]
```

This is an hour right after time EDT ends this year. When I pass it to `ZonedDateTime.parse` I get

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-11-01T01:00-05:00[America/New_York]")
// 2020-11-01T01:00-04:00[America/New_York]
```

but if I do

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-11-01T01:00-04:00[America/New_York]").plusHours(1)
```

I get

```
2020-11-01T01:00-05:00[America/New_York]
```

So it's not like Java cannot represent this ambiguous value or something..

Can anyone explain to me that behavior and possible solution?

Note: I am using Java 8

Comment: sorry but i can not reproduce this. if i do `System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-11-01T01:00-05:00[America/New_York]"));` i get *2020-11-01T01:00-05:00[America/New_York]*. What java version are you using?

Comment: @AmirSchnell I can reproduce on Java 8.

Comment: @Sweeper I was using Java 11, so maybe this is a JDK issue

Comment: @AmirSchnell yes, I am on Java8 as well

Comment: I think this is related to this [link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8066982)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Amir Schnell said in the comments, this seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8066982) in the JDK, as they cannot reproduce this in Java 11.

For now, I have found this work around:

Parse the string into a local date time, zone ID, and zone offset, and create a `ZonedDateTime` using those three things:

```
TemporalAccessor ta = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME.parse("2020-11-01T01:00-05:00[America/New_York]");
System.out.println(
    ZonedDateTime.ofLocal(
        LocalDateTime.from(ta), 
        ZoneId.from(ta), 
        ZoneOffset.from(ta)
    )
);
```